# Horizontal scroll bar problem in silverlight data grid

Tags: silverlight

I'm using silverlight 4 datagrid. I have datagridtextcolumn and also datagrid template column, for them i'm specifying the column with in '*', 'sizetoheader'.

Everything works fine if i have some 20 records in my datagrid, however if my grid have more than 30 records, it's behaving odd. It's like column headers and their columns are not properly aligned, due to this improper alignment, horizontal appears unnecessarily, if i click any of the column header, then everything will be ok. The alignment of column header is exactly with the columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is also happening to me.

In my case, by the moment I set a template to my rows, like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                    <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"    />
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal AlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".65"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#666666"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal Selected">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="5"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" 
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" 
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#ddddff"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver Selected" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="50" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="50" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#ccccff"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>

                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>

                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*">

                            </RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--<Grid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Duration="00:00:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>-->

                        <Border x:Name="Borda"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"  ></Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#1ca0f2" >

                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" FontSize="12" >


                            <localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Name="CellsPresenter" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" >

                            </localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="RowHeader" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" />

                        <localprimitives:DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="DetailsPresenter" />
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="BottomGridLine" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" />
                    </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I get an odd behavior, which is everytime I have horizontal scrollbars available, and I use it, the headers get disaligned with the cells of the rows.

[image: My Headers totally oddly aligned]

For a while, It is working for me if I take the customization of the grid (the codeblock above) from my application, however, I loose some visual styles, which I don't want. If you have it, and do not need it so much, you **could try removing it too**.

Regards!

Clayton Freitas